# Python: how to filter out duplicates in lists by object attributes?

Tags: python

Say I have

```
class a:
    b = 1
thing = a()
thing2 = a()
thing3 = a()
thing3.b = 2
lst = [thing,thing2,thing3]
```

And I want something like this:

```
lst = filter_out(obj.b==obj2.b,lst)
```

result(the objects with same attribute is filtered so that there's only one left):

`[thing2,thing3]`

How can this be achieved? As far as I know, the lambda filter wouldn't work for comparing two objects in a list.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be `[thing,thing2]`?

Comment: `Class` is invalid syntax. It should be `class`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want to delete the duplicated ones, the filter part was a bit confusing so I changed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map objects by their `b` attribute. Since the dict can contain no `b` twice, the dict's values will be your unique elements.

```
>>> unique = {}
>>> for x in lst:
...     unique[x.b] = x
...
>>> list(unique.values())
[<__main__.a object at 0xb724cfcc>, <__main__.a object at 0xb724cfec>]
```

Depending on whether you want to keep the first or the last unique item, either overwrite existing values (as in above code) or add a `if x.b not in unique` check before adding the items.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to overwrite, do `unique.setdefault(x.b, x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use, also, `groupby` from `itertools` module, like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby 

class A:
    b = 1

thing = A()
thing2 = A()
thing3 = A()
thing3.b = 2
lst = [thing, thing2, thing3]
# For testing purpose
dct_id = {id(thing): "thing", id(thing2): "thing2", id(thing3): "thing3"}
# groupping based on each object's b value
sub = [list(v)[-1] for _, v in groupby(lst, lambda x: x.b)]
# check the groupped objects by their id
for k in sub:
    print(dct_id[id(k)])
```

Output:

```
thing2
thing3
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @ tobias_k's comment

If we have this kind of objects:

```
thing = A()
thing2 = A()
thing3 = A()
thing2.b = 2
lst = [thing, thing2, thing3]
```

To avoid bad results, we need to `sort lst` by its object's b value. So `sub` will become:

```
sub = [list(v)[-1] for _, v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.b), lambda x: x.b)]
```

And repeating the same test we'll have:

```
thing3
thing2
```

**Ps:** it's better to sort `sub` list in any case to avoid bad results.

Comment: Try the same with `thing2.b = 2` instead of `thing3.b = 2`. This only works if elements with the same `key` value are adjacent to each other.

Comment: @tobias_k Good point! So here in this case i need to sort `lst` based also on its object's b value. See my last update.